# Norm of spectral projections

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions, projection

I have been reading Kato's perturbation theory book and on spectral theory in general, and I have a question regarding spectral projections and their norms. I'll explain the general setup below.

$X$ is a complex Banach space and $\mathcal{L}:X\to X$ is a bounded operator. Let us suppose that there are two simple isolated eigenvalues $z_1$ and $z_2$ inside some circle $C$. We can define the spectral projection as $\pi=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_C (wI-\mathcal{L})^{-1}dw\in B(X)$, where $B(X)$ is the space of bounded operators on $X$.

Let us define similarly $\pi_1=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_1} (wI-\mathcal{L})^{-1}dw\in B(X)$ to be the eigenprojection of $z_1$. Can we say that $\|\pi_1\|\le \|\pi\|?$ (operator norm)

Intuitively, it seems like it should hold (we are projecting onto a smaller region of the space). But I can not seem to show it. The best I can show is $\|\pi_1\|\le \|\pi_1\|\|\pi\|$ (since $\pi_1=\pi_1\circ \pi$). Does anyone know if this is true, or am I just goose hunting?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can fail already for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces. Let:
$$A(e_2)=2 e_2, \qquad A(e_1+e_2)=e_1+e_2$$
ie
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

The projection $\pi_1$ satisfies $\pi_1(e_1+e_2)=e_1+e_2$ and $\pi_1(e_2)=0$, hence it is equal to $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. The projection $\pi$ is the identity, and clearly $\|\pi_1\|>1=\|\pi\|$.

Comment: I do not think this argument works. Look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220490/is-the-sum-of-spectral-projections-a-projection. From this we see that my projection $\pi=\pi_1+\pi_2$ where $\pi_1$ is as above and $\pi_2$ is the corresponding spectral projection for $z_2$. Your $\pi_1$ is a constant multiple of my $\pi_1$, (and it does not satisfy $\pi_1^2=\pi_1$).

Comment: $\pi_1$ does satisfy the equation $\pi_1^2=\pi_1$, otherwise it wouldn't be a projection. Notice that in the math overflow answer he says it is true if the operator is a **self-adjoint** compact operator (emphasis from me on self-adjoint). For this example the fact that $A$ is not self-adjoint is essential.

Comment: In the stackoverflow comments for the answer, it is mentioned that for finite sums and the operator being closed, the formula is valid in general. In particular it should hold for my continuous operator $\mathcal{L}:X\to X$, no?

Comment: In fact, I am not actually sure I understand your solution. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,2$. I can not seem to place you projection $\pi_1$. According to my question, you either want to consider the projection onto the eigenspace of $1$, or that of $2$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: $\pi_1$ is the projection on the eigenvalue $1$. I just checked the integral with mathematica (once along the curve of radius $3/2$ and once along radius $3$) and $\pi_1$ and $\pi=\Bbb1$ were indeed the results.